# Internal eroor 500 drupal store

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internal-server-error, commerce

my website is working fine. Only the store is returning internal error 500. It opens but when someone clicks a product it returns "the site is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Please, what can be the cause. I have increased the upload_max_time and post_max-size yet it can't be resolved

Edit: Checking the server log I got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/K80jN.png

Comment: enable theme debug and check your template files. Drupal 7 templates are written in PHP and error 500 is an application server error.

Comment: Looking at the server logs, I find some 500 errors on modules, I also tried updating modules and I get a white page.

Comment: Try turning on all php error reporting like [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing)